# Revolution Slider works in localhost but not on server

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, laravel-blade

I am using revolution slider which works fine in localhost but doesn't show images when my website is uploaded on server. The code is here:

```
<div id="revolutionSlider" class="slider rev_slider" data-version="5.4.7" data-plugin-revolution-slider data-plugin-options="{'delay': 9000, 'sliderLayout': 'standard', 'gridwidth': [1140,960,720,540], 'gridheight': [600,600,600,600], 'disableProgressBar': 'on', 'responsiveLevels': [4096,1200,992,576], 'navigation' : {'arrows': { 'enable': true, 'hide_under': 767, 'style': 'slider-arrows-style-1 slider-arrows-light' }, 'bullets': {'enable': true, 'style': 'bullets-style-1', 'h_align': 'center', 'v_align': 'bottom', 'space': 7, 'v_offset': 35, 'h_offset': 0}}}">

                <ul>
                    <li data-transition="fade">
                        <img src="{{asset('frontimages/slide-1-1.jpg')}}"  
                            alt=""
                            data-bgposition="center" 
                            data-bgfit="cover" 
                            data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" 
                            data-kenburns="on" 
                            data-duration="2500" 
                            data-ease="Power2.easeInOut" 
                            data-scalestart="125" 
                            data-scaleend="100" 
                            data-rotatestart="0" 
                            data-rotateend="0" 
                            data-blurstart="20" 
                            data-blurend="0" 
                            data-offsetstart="0 0" 
                            data-offsetend="0 0"
                            class="rev-slidebg">

                        <div class="tp-caption text-color-light font-primary font-weight-bold"
                            data-x="left" data-hoffset="['52','52','17','17']"
                            data-y="center" data-voffset="['-80','-80','-80','-70']"
                            data-start="1000"
                            data-fontsize="['55','55','55','55']"
                            data-lineheight="['60','60','60','60']"
                            data-transform_in="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-transform_out="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;">ACCESSIBLE &</div>

                        <div class="tp-caption text-color-light font-primary font-weight-bold"
                            data-x="left" data-hoffset="['50','50','15','15']"
                            data-y="center" data-voffset="['-30','-30','-30','-30']"
                            data-start="1000"
                            data-fontsize="['55','55','55','47']"
                            data-lineheight="['60','60','60','52']"
                            data-transform_in="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-transform_out="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;">AFFORDABLE</div>

                        <div class="tp-caption text-color-light font-primary"
                            data-x="left" data-hoffset="['50','50','15','15']"
                            data-y="center" data-voffset="['30','30','30','15']"
                            data-start="1000"
                            data-fontsize="['18','18','18','18']"
                            data-lineheight="['25','25','25','25']"
                            data-transform_in="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-transform_out="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;">PRODUCTS <span class="bg-dark text-color-light font-weight-bold p-1">UPTO 20% OFF</span></div>

                        <a class="tp-caption btn btn-rounded btn-primary font-weight-semibold text-1"
                            href="{{route('allproducts')}}"
                            data-x="left" data-hoffset="['50','50','15','15']"
                            data-y="center" data-voffset="['115','115','115','115']"
                            data-start="1600"
                            data-whitespace="nowrap"
                            data-fontsize="['13','14','14','14']"
                            data-paddingtop="['13','14','14','14']"
                            data-paddingbottom="['13','13','13','16']"
                            data-paddingleft="['70','70','70','70']"
                            data-paddingright="['70','70','70','70']"    
                            data-transform_in="y:[-50%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-transform_out="y:[50%];opacity:0;s:500;">SHOP NOW</a>
                        
                    </li>
                    <li data-transition="fade">
                        <img src="{{asset('frontimages/slide-1-2.jpg')}}"  
                            alt=""
                            data-bgposition="center center" 
                            data-bgfit="cover" 
                            data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" 
                            data-kenburns="on" 
                            data-duration="2500" 
                            data-ease="Power2.easeInOut" 
                            data-scalestart="125" 
                            data-scaleend="100" 
                            data-rotatestart="0" 
                            data-rotateend="0" 
                            data-blurstart="20" 
                            data-blurend="0" 
                            data-offsetstart="0 0" 
                            data-offsetend="0 0"
                            class="rev-slidebg">

                        <div class="tp-caption text-color-light font-primary font-weight-bold"
                            data-x="left" data-hoffset="['750','630','420','290']"
                            data-y="center" data-voffset="['-80','-80','-80','-70']"
                            data-start="1000"
                            data-fontsize="['55','55','55','55']"
                            data-lineheight="['60','60','60','60']"
                            data-transform_in="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-transform_out="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;">CONVENIENCE</div>

                        <div class="tp-caption text-color-light font-primary font-weight-bold"
                            data-x="left" data-hoffset="['750','630','420','290']"
                            data-y="center" data-voffset="['-30','-30','-30','-30']"
                            data-start="1000"
                            data-fontsize="['55','55','55','47']"
                            data-lineheight="['60','60','60','52']"
                            data-transform_in="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-transform_out="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;">DELIVERED</div>

                        <div class="tp-caption text-color-light font-primary"
                            data-x="left" data-hoffset="['750','630','420','290']"
                            data-y="center" data-voffset="['30','30','30','15']"
                            data-start="1000"
                            data-fontsize="['18','18','18','18']"
                            data-lineheight="['25','25','25','25']"
                            data-transform_in="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-transform_out="y:[100%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;">MORE THAN <span class="bg-light text-color-dark font-weight-bold p-1">500 PRODUCTS</span></div>

                        <a class="tp-caption btn btn-rounded btn-primary font-weight-semibold text-1"
                            href="{{route('allproducts')}}"
                            data-x="left" data-hoffset="['750','630','420','290']"
                            data-y="center" data-voffset="['115','115','115','115']"
                            data-start="1600"
                            data-whitespace="nowrap"
                            data-fontsize="['13','14','14','14']"
                            data-paddingtop="['13','14','14','14']"
                            data-paddingbottom="['13','13','13','16']"
                            data-paddingleft="['70','70','70','70']"
                            data-paddingright="['70','70','70','70']"    
                            data-transform_in="y:[-50%];opacity:0;s:500;"
                            data-transform_out="y:[50%];opacity:0;s:500;">SHOP NOW</a>
                        
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Now what should i do? I have included all the css files as i have done locally, but i don't know why the problem occurs. Even all the permissions have been granted to access images. Other images are showing but not the one in slider.

This is the exception which shows in console log of server but doesn't shows up in the console log of localhost.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'layers' of undefined
at Function.animateTheCaptions (jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:41)
at swapSlideProgress (jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:8)
at Object.target (jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:8)
at Object.h._callback (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60)
at Object.h.render (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60)
at Object.h.render (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60)
at Object.D._updateRoot.G.render (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60)
at Object.h.dispatchEvent (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60)
at s (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I simply changed the script of the Jquery code from http:\ to https:\